# Correct regex pattern

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I would like to match the following list of files with a single PCRE regex pattern

```
27919506_7368.jpg
27965477_68.jpg
52345652_1-4.jpg
65849674_245.jpg
54839756_34-9.jpg
```

What I've come up to so far is this `\d{8}_\d{1,4}\.jpg`, however, this fails to match the `-\d+` variations...

Likewise, this `\d{8}_\d{1,4}-\d+\.jpg` fails to match the non `-\d+` variations...

What would the correct pattern be that would match all of the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/GYlfkL/1), `\d{8}_[\d-]{1,4}\.jpg`.

- `\d{8}_`: Matches eight digits followed by `_`
- `[\d-]{1,4}`: Matches a digit or `-`, one to four times
- `\.jpg`: Matches `.jpg`